# dynamic pivot ordering

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have transferred rows into columns using pivot and result of dynamic columns as follows `,cat_v1 ,cost_v1 ,...`. I want to change order so that display all category then cost: `cat_v1, ... ,cat_vi, cost_v1,...,cost_vi`

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT ID , description, FN , cat , cost 
  FROM invt
)
Pivot 
(
  Max (cat) as cat , max ( cost)  as cost 
  FOR FN in (' ||  p_fn || ') 
)
```

Comment: provide minimal, reproducible question with sample data and desired output values please.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```sql
SELECT *
```

To named columns in the desired order:

```sql
SELECT id, description, cat_v1, cat_v2, cat_v3, cost_v1, cost_v2, cost_v3
```

If you are dynamically generating the `IN` clause of the pivot then you will also have to dynamically generate the columns to select.

Comment: Dear, yeas pivot cause is dynamic.as shown above. Note that current result is cat for first variable of pivot clause then cost for same variable but I wanted to show cat_v1,... Cat_vn then cost_v1,.... Cost_vn